# Java, serialization, writeObject method, making references

Tags: java, performance, serialization, memory-efficient

I'm overriding the writeObject method for a class for serialization.
The class is a list based class.
I need to make it memory efficient for the case that Nodes in the list contain the same keys.
So instead of sending over multiple keys that are identical I want to send over references to the same keys.

My basic goal is to make sure I don't write out duplicate keys.  If there are duplicate keys I want to make sure I only send out a key once and then only send out references to it afterwards.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out){
    try{ // Attempt to write data out
        out.writeInt(size); // size is number of Nodes in list
        ArrayList<Node> reverse = new ArrayList<Node>();
        // Reverse the order to write out so readObject builds correctly
        for(Node c = head; c != null; c = c.next)
            reverse.add(0, c);      
        for(Node c: reverse){ // Break down objects and write out
            out.writeObject(c.key);
            out.writeObject(c.val);
        }

    } // Catch any exceptions
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("seriallist writeobject");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is the code that I have working correctly for serializing the data.  I've tried to make a list of all unique keys and attempted to have each node reference one of those keys, but I haven't been able to get the file size down when I write out.

Also ideally I would like to make the references inside of this method so I only have to worry about doing it before writing out instead of maintaining them during adding/removing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Java serialization will actually _already do this for you._  References to the same object (by reference equality, not object equality) will not be repeated.

Comment: Are you talking about if I didn't override this method?  Or if the list contains references then this method I wrote will automatically take care of it for me?

Comment: Well if you were talking about if I already had references in my list then I know that but I'm trying to create references instead of having each key be unique.

Comment: If you have two nodes `c1` and `c2` where `c1.key == c2.key`, then that object will only be serialized once, and when it gets deserialized again it will still be the case that `c1.key == c2.key`.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish right before I send my data out.

Comment: "If you have two nodes c1 and c2 where c1.key == c2.key, then that object will only be serialized once, and when it gets deserialized again it will still be the case that c1.key == c2.key." is what _already happens_ with Java serialization.

Comment: OK so you're saying that if the keys have object equality then it will take care of it for me?  I believe the underlying reason I have to do this is for when strings are the keys.  Because strings don't have object equality in Java right?  So if I had two Nodes with their keys being "one" but not references to each other I don't believe using the == on them would return true.

Comment: That's correct, but it may simplify your task -- e.g. using `intern()` instead of trying to manage the sharing yourself.

Comment: I'm not guaranteed to have Strings as the keys unfortunately.

Comment: Then use a `Map<Foo, Foo>` to do your own interning; it's not massively difficult.  It's still easier than trying to hack around serialization yourself.